# Migrating from SQL Server to Aurora PostgreSQL where encountering GUID, VARCHAR, UUID issues

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, entity-framework-6, npgsql, aws-dms

I'm seeking some advice.

I've migrated a database from SQL Server to Aurora PostgreSQL using AWS DMS. In most of the tables in SQL Server, the primary keys are a `uniqueidentifier` (GUID). When migrated to Postgres these columns are converted to `VARCHAR(36)`. This seems to be as expected, per the AWS DMS documentation.

In our .NET application, we use Entity Framework 6, which I have added a new dbContext to use the npgsql provider. Note that we are still keeping existing SQL Server EF6 providers. Essentially, the application will use both SQL Server and PostgreSQL. This is all hooked up fine.

Where I run into some issues is when my Postgres context is making fetches to the PostgreSQL database, it encounters a lot of errors

> Npgsql.PostgresException: 42883: operator does not exist: character varying = uuid

I understand the issue, where the application using EF makes a fetch by Id (GUID), and the Postgres table has an Id that is `VARCHAR` type...

My feeling is the problem is not on the application or EF side, rather the column on the table should be something like a UUID. Which I can do, on post migration, I can simply alter the column to become a UUID type, but is this the way, and will it resolve my issues? I also feel like this can't be a unique case I'm dealing with; seems like a common issue for anyone also migrating a .NET app from SQL Server to PostgreSQL...

I look forward to hearing some of your ideas, comments, thoughts on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never had expreience with AWS DMS but ut looks like migration went wrong if `uniqueidentifier` converted to `varchar`. Have you tried `ALTER TABLE [table_with_guid]   ALTER [guid_field] SET TYPE uuid NOT NULL` ?

Comment: Pretty sure the migration is correct according to the documentation. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html#CHAP_Source.SQLServer.DataTypes

That being said, there is the ability to make transformation rules on migration. However, none of the data-type I can convert to on migration are UUID. See:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html

Comment: Your suggestion to alter columns to UUID post migration is do-able, just a lot of tables to do, probably will need to script this...Was hoping someone has gone through this experience and how they might have overcome this situation...

Comment: This seems like an error in the conversion tool (at least if the "uniqueidentifier" values are valid UUIDs)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this migration procedure is not quite up to the task, as a GUID (which is Microsoft's confusing term for UUID) should be migrated to `uuid`. Not only would you save 21 bytes of storage space per row, but you also wouldn't have this problem.

It seems that your application is comparing a `uuid` value with one of the migrated `varchar`s:

```
WHERE uniqueidentifier = UUID '87595807-3157-4a81-ac89-3e09e83c0c0a'
```

You have to add an explicit cast, like the error message says:

```
WHERE uniqueidentifier = CAST (UUID '87595807-3157-4a81-ac89-3e09e83c0c0a' AS text)
```

You would cast to `text`, not to `varchar`, because there is no equality operator for `varchar`. `varchar` is coerced to `text` when you compare it, because the storage for these types is identical.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I understand this (the casting of the uuid/text)...My understanding is if I used EF6 and npgsql, I should not have to deal with this kind of casting manipulation, or at the very least minimal amount of it. Based on most people's response, perhaps I will further explore the migration process and see if I can migrate the GUID as a UUID.

Comment: The smartness of ORMs is limited.